# premake: how to get a list of the defined configurations?

Tags: premake

ie, I'd like a hypothetical function `get_configurations()` that would let me do something like this in my `premake5.lua`:

```lua
workspace "myworkspace"
    configurations { "debug", "release" }
project "myproject"
    configurations { "projconfig" }
    for _, cfg in ipairs(get_configurations()) do
        print(cfg)
    end
```

...and have it output:

```
debug
release
projconfig
```

Is this possible? I saw that there is `premake.configset`, but it's not clear how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. In your simple example it looks easy, but in larger projects there may be many considerations that go into deciding what values end up in that list. It could be filtered by target platform, or toolset, or any number of other variables. Some later block may remove a value that was set earlier. The actual list can't be determined until after all scripts have been run and the final configuration is compiled for export.

However, Premake is just Lua, so you can always define a list of configurations and associate it with a variable, or [wrap your settings up in a function](https://premake.github.io/docs/Sharing-Configuration-Settings) and pass in the values.